# I'm using Azure AD and would like to set up a VPN so that everyone shares the same IP Address

Tags: networking, vpn, azure, azure-networking, point-to-site-vpn

software developer here that's been assigned the role of sys admin. Apologies for what might be "the wrong question".

I have set up Azure AD and have 10 laptops added to the domain. The staff are working from home but I need them all to share the same static IP Address so we can register that IP with one of our partners.

I believe I need a point-to-site vpn but I'm not sure that's going to give me a single static IP. Does anyone know what product (or conbination of products) I might need to achieve this ("simple") task.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to purchase a VPN gateway to achieve this
I believe that once it's set up correctly, it should offer you a range of IP Addresses your users can pick from when they sign on.

See here for more details
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about